# Gravity's effect on time

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime

How can we say the time gets faster or slower when we are measuring time using tangible objects (like a caesium clock) .
Can't we say that gravity is affecting the oscillation of the caesium clock and hence it's showing error in time?
Also does this mean that time is nothing if we don't measure it or time exist only if we measure it?

And our body cells have their own biological clock so why would they even respond to the change in time and they'll complete their cell cycle normally {24 hours in human (but that's what we have calculated cell doesn't have information for the time  it works on it's own pace)} so will they age less than others (I'm supposing that their time gets slowed down)?

And if this should happen of course due to gravity then does it mean that even DNA replication all the way down to sub atomic level is affected by the gravity and the enzyme gets slower and slower?

Comment: Most happenings in the universe as we perceive it is governed by time. So when time slows every cause-result happenings slow down, our biological processes, oscillation movement and everything else. I also think cesium clock is accurate and doesn't show "time error" but time itself has slowed down compared to a different reference. Also if time slows, ever molecule moves slower and since all biochemical actions are molecular, if time slows aging slows too(of course,relative to eartians)

Comment: On body clocks, the implication of this interpretation is that a gravity field affects the pace at which *all* fundamental physical processes occur - and therefore all the physical processes that underpin the body clock are affected to the same degree as an engineered clock. Some find that surprising, but we are dealing with fundamental physics and all-permeating forces after all.

Comment: @TheInfinity, is there any *scientific or engineering basis* for thinking that the cesium clock is "accurate", and that it is immune from influence from fundamental physical forces? We have experimental evidence to know that cesium clocks do vary with gravitational field - what is the experimental basis for excluding measurement error from the explanation, and attributing it instead to a change in the "flow of time"?

Comment: Of course there will be difference in time shown by 2 same cesium clocks with one on earth and other under high gravitational influence. I only meant to say that it is not an error because if time slows then shouldn't the clock slow down because oscillation slows down. I'm not sure though if this actually is called error.

Comment: FWIW, in a modern [atomic fountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_fountain) caesium clock the atoms that provide the time signal are in free fall, so they are weightless, but their oscillation is nevertheless time dilated by the gravitational potential. (Those fountain atoms are also laser cooled down to near absolute zero).

Comment: @TheInfinity, but his question concerns the very distinction between measurement error and "time itself" being influenced. We know all sorts of physical influences upset clocks - turn the room thermostat up, for example, and many kinds of clock alter their rate. How can we be sure that gravity is not simply upsetting the cesium clock and also his body clock, and that meanwhile time itself has carried on merrily as before? What distinguishes the "time slowing down" case from the "measurement error under physical influence" case?

Answer (score 5):

> Can't we say that gravity is affecting the oscillation of caesium clock and hence it's showing error in time?

The point is that cesium clocks, mechanical clocks, quartz clocks, clocks based on radioactive decay, biological clocks, and clocks of any other possible mechanism all slow down by the exact same amount.

So there are two possibilities. Either these clocks are all measuring the same underlying construct, or different clocks measure different underlying constructs. If they all measure the same construct then we call that construct “time”, and they correctly show that time is dilating. If they are each measuring a different construct then they are each being slowed down by a different mechanism and those different mechanisms in principle could each have a different dilation but just by pure coincidence the slowing all happen to be identical.

So far, time dilation has been observed for electromagnetism, the strong interaction, the weak interaction, and gravity. All of the observations fit the predictions of relativity. No plausible super-coincidental mechanistic explanation has been proposed, but if one were to be proposed then it would have many more free parameters than relativity so it would generally be rejected on philosophical grounds such as Occham’s razor.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106844/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-gravitys-effect-on-time).

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to think about time dilation is to consider a special kind of clock that consists of two perfect mirrors, facing each other with a photon bouncing back and forth between them. We'll have this clock "tick" every time the light bounces off the top mirror. (We'll come back to gravity in a bit.)

[image]

The image on the left shows a light clock in its rest frame. The light bounces up and down. Because light travels at c, and the distance between the mirrors is d, then one tick on the clock takes an amount of time $t = 2d/c$

The image on the right shows how this clock looks to an observer moving to the left at some speed $v$. Now the path the beam of light travels from one mirror to the other is longer. We can use trigonometry and the fact that the light still travels at $c$ to calculate the time of a single tick as observed by the moving observer.

Noting that the speed of light is still $c$ and using Pythagorus's theorem we can calculate the distance traveled by light as observed by the moving observer in one tick as the observer sees it. We'll call the amount of time for one tick as the observer sees it $t'$.

According to the observer, the light takes a path with length $t' c$ in one tick. So the hypotenuse of one of those triangles is $\frac{1}{2} t' c$. The height is still d, so the base is $\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2} t' c)^2 - d^2}$. But we know the observer sees the clock moving at $v$ so the base is also $\frac{1}{2}t' v$. Setting those equal, we get:

$\frac{1}{2}t' v = \sqrt{(\frac{1}{2} t' c)^2 - d^2}$

With some algebra, we can solve for $t'$:

$t' = \frac{2d}{c} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$

Notice that if $v = 0$ we get our original time back. But the moving observer sees the clock taking longer to tick. Notice that we're not doing anything to the clock. In this case, we're talking about a moving observer. So we can see that time can be observed to slow down even without gravity affecting the motion of particles.

Understanding how gravity causes time dilation is an additional challenge. It breaks down, basically, like this: gravity is equivalent to acceleration. Now imagine rotating this image $90^\circ$ and drop it from some large height. It's now accelerating downward. An observer falling along side the clock with see the ticks tick back and forth at $2d/c$ again. But an observer on the ground, watching it fall will again see light take a longer path (and it will take ever longer paths for each consecutive tick). So this observer will again see time dilation.

But we don't need the clock to be falling. Instead, the clock could be stationary and the observer could be falling. So again, nothing 'weird' is happening to the clock. The clock hasn't been changed at all. It's all a matter of its *relative* motion to the observer.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let's take two cesium atoms, one on the suface of Earth, one in space.

Now gravitational time dilation will cause the two atoms to go through relatively different amounts of hyperfine transitions during a certain period of time.

When viewed from Earth, the atom in space will undergo more hyperfine transitions, then the atom on the surface of Earth.

The atom inside Earth's gravitational field can only undergo relatively less hyperfine transitions. You are asking why? You are saying that the gravitational field of Earth does have some effect on the atom inside it (inside the gravitational field) and causes some error.

You can call it whatever you want, but we see in the experiments that there is this effect of gravity on the atom.

According to the equivalence principle, this effect of gravity is indistinguishable from acceleration.

Thus, we can say that the atom inside the gravitational field undergoes acceleration, and this causes this atom to undergo less hyperfine transitions relatively then the atom in space.

You are asking why? There is a example with photon clocks as they accelerate, analogously. The reasoning is that the movement of the photon is affected by the acceleration, thus the photon in the gravitational field has to travel allover longer paths relatively to the photon in space. Thus the photon clock in the gravitational field will relatively tick slower then the photon clock in space.

> In atomic physics, hyperfine structure is defined by small shifts and splittings[clarification needed] in the energy levels of atoms, molecules, and ions, due to interaction between the state of the nucleus and the state of the electron clouds.
>   Hyperfine structure, with energy shifts typically orders of magnitudes smaller than those of a fine-structure shift, results from the interactions of the nucleus (or nuclei, in molecules) with internally generated electric and magnetic fields.

Now you are asking whether this acceleration is causing some error in the atom, making it relatively do less hyperfine transitions. You could imagine that the hyperfine transition requires the nucleus and the electrons in the atom to interact. This requires time. Analogously to the photon clock, this interaction between the nucleus and electrons (the hyperfine transition) seems to require relatively more time.

In reality we do not know what the underlying mechanism (it is all QM) is that causes the interaction to take more time, but it might be that it is similar to the photon clock, and the interaction between the nucleus and electrons requires more time simply because of the acceleration (caused by the gravitational field) requiring longer paths and that is (information propagation) ultimately limited by the speed of light.

If you accept that the underlying world is quantum mechanical and information propagation is limited by the speed of light, then the answer is that the gravitational field causes (has the same effect as) acceleration and that causes the atom to undergo relatively less hyperfine transitions.