# Can we provide a universal clock with atomic clock?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, time, atomic-clocks

If we use normal clocks then due to the relativiy there will be misleading time, but what will happen with certain atomic clocks with less mistake and relative? If we can measure the time, what accuracy can we get? And will relativy effect the atomick clock measurement?

Thanks from now

Comment: Yes, relativity impacts atomic clocks. You can do fun experiments like take one up a mountain, bring it back down, and compare with one left at base altitude. And the GPS satellite atomic clocks experience relativistic changes. Nothing magic about an atomic clock.

Comment: @JonCuster thank you.

Comment: See for example https://www.wired.com/2007/12/time-hackers/

Comment: The discrepancy in time measured between observers in different frames of reference isn't an issue of inaccurate measurement. A theoretical perfect time measuring device would still measure time dilation. Time dilation is a real effect and not an artifact of some lack of understand or technology we have. You may be interested in reading about 'photon clocks' see this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544389/gravitys-effect-on-time/544411#544411

Comment: As this Dale says in [this recent answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/544398/123208) "The point is that cesium clocks, mechanical clocks, quartz clocks, clocks based on radioactive decay, biological clocks, and clocks of any other possible mechanism all slow down [due to relativity] by the exact same amount."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time is still relative even when measured by an atomic clock. Because of their extreme accuracy, atomic clocks are used to test relativity. For example, they were used in the [Hafele-Keating experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment).

Comment: I see thank you. I googled it a bit but i couldn't find that. Thanks!